# Android App Launcher in ReactNative like Microsoft, Google Launcher

Tags: android, react-native, android-launcher, app-launcher

I am wondering if it is possible to develop an App Launcher application for Android.
I am referring to the app launcher introduced by different vendors, i.e. Microsoft App Launcher, Google App Launcher, and many more...

I could not find any library that could help me in this regard. If this is not possible by ReactNative then how and in which technology I could achieve this goal.

Comment: I think the best of React Native is you can use it for different platforms. But this seems to be like Android only app so it will be better to use Java or Kotlin. I'm not sure about launchers. But gestures can be done easily with Gesture Responder System in RN it's a good one to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I have found the possible solution, which could lead me as initial guide to develop **Android App Launcher** application.

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/RNLauncher

*This is a simple custom Launcher Application for Android Made with `React Native`. It is a good project for beginners to understand `react native` and `native bridge`.

> As a side note these libraries might also help to achieve a specific goal if we have in specific plan:
>
> > https://github.com/MrToph/react-native-app-launcher
> >
> > *React-Native library for Android that can schedule automatic launches of your app at specific times.*
>
> http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by changing the AndroidManifest.xml

Under the `<intent-filter>` in the XML add the following two lines

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```